# Double != null is causing a NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have the following snippet of code that is causing me bother, where currentRate and secondCurrentRate are Double objects, correctly defined:

```
(currentRate != null && secondCurrentRate != null) ? currentRate * secondCurrentRate : null;
```

This should check each each Double for null-ness and assign the value null accordingly. However, if secondCurrentRate is null, this causes a NullPointerException. 
I have changed the snippet to this:

```
(currentRate == null | secondCurrentRate == null) ? null : currentRate * secondCurrentRate;
```

And this works as expected. My question is why is this happening? I could understand it if I was calling some method on the objects but my understanding was that NullPointerExceptions were thrown when a method was called on a null object. There is a null object but there is no method call.

Can anyone offer any insight into this? This is running in Java 5.

Comment: In your second snippet, is it "||" or "|"?

Comment: @Thierry-Dimitri Roy it's the same thing in this case.

Comment: Please provide a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: What happens if you swith the 2nd around to (secondCurrentRate == null | currentRate == null)...?

Comment: I've tried your original code (under 1.6, but i don't believe the rules have changed) and it works as you intended, not as your report. Are you certain this is the code you tried? What are you doing with the value of this expression? Could it be that you're assigning it to a lowercase-d double, and getting a NPE on unboxing?

Comment: I thought it may have been a problem with unboxing to a primative (it is being assigned to a primitve) but I singled out the secondCurrentRate != null part in Eclipse and resolved just that expression (CTRL+SHIFT+I for those who don't know how to do that) and that threw a NullPointerException on its own.

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem is elsewhere.

This works :

```
    Double currentRate=null, secondCurrentRate =null;
    Double test = (currentRate != null && secondCurrentRate != null) ? currentRate * secondCurrentRate : null;
```

But if you've done this, it will cause a NPE:

```
    Double currentRate=null, secondCurrentRate =null;
    double test = (currentRate != null && secondCurrentRate != null) ? currentRate * secondCurrentRate : null;
```

Comment: 0  down vote
 

I've just tried this and while the compiler doesn't allow double a = null; it will happily let you write double a = 0.0 > 1.0 ? a : null; which will compile but throw NPE. That's psychic power debugging you are doing here ;-)

Comment: In fact with the ternary operator, the JVM will consider null as a `Double` then unbox it into a `double` and then crash :)

Answer (score 2):

The type of the conditional operator is actually [quite complicated](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#290293). I *believe* what happens in your first example, is this: The second operand of the conditional,

```
currentRate * secondCurrentRate
```

is of type `double`, and this also becomes the type of the entire expression. Then, when either of the values are null, it tries to set the value of the expression to the `Double` null, which is unboxed into a `double` and causes a NPE.

The reason the second expression works is due to slightly different semantics of the conditional expression in this case.