# Autoboxing is not working for instance variables?

Tags: java, autoboxing

I defined a Double instance variable like this:

```
public class CurrencyActivity extends Activity {

    private Button convertBtn;
    private Double SEKrate;

....
public void convertCurrency() {
....
Double inputNum = Double.parseDouble(editTextStr);
Double result = inputNum*SEKrate;
....
}
....
}
```

When running, it says NullPointer exception at the line

```
Double result = inputNum*SEKrate;
```

It seems like SEKrate is initialized to null, but autoboxing is not performed here. any thought on this?

Comment: And where do you make `SEKrate` something other than `null`, exactly? Also ... don't start variable names with uppercase letters.

Comment: A related thread on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547804/double-null-is-causing-a-nullpointerexception

Comment: this code is written by someone else, I am debugging it - sorry about non-java variable names. Obviously as an instance variable, SEKrate is initialzed to null and there is no other assignment to it before the line in issue. so the compiler sees null as a Double and tries to unboxing it, then NPE throws.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not initialize a `Double` it is `null` and `null` can not be unboxed to a `double`.

So initalize your variable.

```
  private Double SEKrate=0;
```